# How to extend AWS EventBridge event with new field or override existing field

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I have an integration between AWS EventBridge and AWS Lambda. I'm using aws-cdk to create Rule.

Let's say I have EB event in the following format

```json
{
  "event": {
    "version": "0",
    "id": "e7e4d675-1bea-ad19-ffa3-4d6e962e15af",
    "detail-type": "SOMETHING_HAPPENED",
    "source": "source",
    "account": "111111111111",
    "time": "2023-02-23T14:52:34Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
      "data": { "key": "value" },
      "metadata": { "correlation-id": "some uuid" }
    }
  }
}
```

In my AWS lambda, as an input, I want to omit metadata and set details = nested data but keep other fields

```json
{
  "event": {
    "version": "0",
    "id": "e7e4d675-1bea-ad19-ffa3-4d6e962e15af",
    "detail-type": "SOMETHING_HAPPENED",
    "source": "source",
    "account": "111111111111",
    "time": "2023-02-23T14:52:34Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": { "key": "value" }
  }
}
```

The documentation lacks of examples or hidden somewhere.

Is it possible to enrich or replace subset of fields of the original event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EventBridge Input Transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html) is the feature for you.

It does exactly what you need: transforming an event input before it's passed to the consumer.

You can configure it from CloudFormation / Terraform or from the Console UI, in the step "Configure Target" (third step), under the "Additional Settings" -> "Configure target input" section.

Based on your question, your Input Transformer configuration should be something like:

```
{
  "version" : "$.version",
  "id" : "$.id",
  ...and so on... 
  "detail": "$.detail.data"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that I need to use input transformation. I'm already using it. I don't understand how to make it work in the way I need (or if it's even possible)

Comment: Answer updated with an example of how to fit your use case (omitting metadata and take just the data in the detail)

Comment: I see, I'd like to avoid the duplication of all the fields. In other words, I'm looking for something like js spread operator: newEvent = {...oldEvent, detail: oldEvent.detail.data}

Comment: That's not possibly, unfortunately: anyway you can't compare a feature from a programming language with a simple template / mapping definition ;) If you want a more granular mapping, using event JS if you want, you should pre-process the event with a Lambda Function, and the send the updated message to the real processor.